# How to generate extent reports using spark (ExtentReports 5)?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng, extentreports, selenium-extent-report

Now Htmlreporter is deprecating. So need other than Htmlreporter solution. Please give me the proper and new solution.Am expecting with the spark report.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The usage remains same, albeit with the new default reporter.

```
ExtentSparkReporter spark = new ExtentSparkReporter(new File(""));
extent.attachReporter(spark);
```

Comment: Also use in this way too                                                                                            ExtentSparkReporter spark = new ExtentSparkReporter("target/Spark.html");
extent.attachReporter(spark);